# Convert string time in min:sec:milsec to numeric seconds

Tags: r, time

I want to convert a column of string times in the format above e.g. `"1:25:499"`, I simply want as an output the time in seconds (float) `85.499`.

I tried setting `options(digits.secs =3)` and running `strptime(df$times, "%OSn")` to get it into an intermediary form to convert then into a flat seconds float.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string by `":"`, then multiply and sum the component numbers:

```
c("1:25:499", "3:09:004") |>
  strsplit(":") |>
  sapply(\(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * c(60, 1, 1/1000)))
# 85.499 189.004
```

Seems like there should be a way of doing this by coercing to a `"difftime"`, then `"double"`, but I wasn’t able to find one that preserved the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution converting the last colon into a period and then using the lubridate package to convert the string into seconds.

```
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)

#replace the last colon with a period
time_with_period <- sub(":(\\d+?)$", "\\.\\1", "1:25:499")

#convert from string to a period and
# then into seconds
answer <- ms(time_with_period) %>% period_to_seconds()
answer
```